# How to get the count of boolean value in just object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have to get the length of boolean value (if it is true) in just an object. 
Can anyone help me solve this?

```
var data = {
             mo: true, 
             tu: true, 
             we: true, 
             th: true, 
             fr: true, 
             sa: false, 
             su: false
           };
```

Comment: `total = 0;for (k in data) total += data[k]`. In numeric operations, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so....

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(data).length`

Comment: what do you mean by length of boolean value

Comment: In a modern environment, I'd probably do `let count = 0; for (const flag of Object.values(data)) { if (flag) { ++total; } }`, but [you have lots of options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263127/157247). As @Adelin points out, you could make use of the fact that a boolean when converted to a number is 1 if true or 0 if false, so just `total += flag;` in the loop would work too.

Comment: @Adelin - 1 that! :-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L5ft9s4v/

Answer (score 5):

Here are two ways to do it (modern & shorter vs. backwards-compatible & longer):

```js
var data = {
             mo: true, 
             tu: true, 
             we: true, 
             th: true, 
             fr: true, 
             sa: false, 
             su: false
           };

const short = Object.values(data).filter((v) => v).length;

var long = 0;

for (var prop in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop) && data[prop]) {
    long++;
  }
}

console.log(short, long);
```

In the modern version, we take only the values in the object, filter out any that aren’t truthy, and take the length of the resulting array.

In the backwards-compatible version, we loop through the properties of the object, filter out any that aren’t its own properties or aren’t truthy, and increment the count.

Comment: Woah! this one worked like a charm. **Thank you so much!** Sorry, I couldn't up-vote for your answer guys. I'm really grateful

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple way to do it

```
function totalBoolean(data){
 booleanTotal = 0;
 for (key in data) 
 booleanTotal += data[key]
 return booleanTotal;
}

var total = totalBoolean(data)
```